# Communicating between activities (Android)

Tags: android

If I want to pass message to a started activity how do I go about doing it? Cannot use Intent.put... as my activity is already started.

Comment: Where do you send it from. Without more details we will not be able to help you.

Comment: Ok. I have 2 activities. the first activity have a Handler which will receive result from service. So now is if I have started a the second activity thru Intent i = new Intent(something); StartActivity(); how does the Handler in the first activity pass messages to the started 2nd activity

Answer (score 1):

U can use onNewIntent() in your activity

the activity can be sent an updated intent for the work

Answer (score 0):

You can save an instance of this activity somewhere and call a method to send your message by parameters.

**Sender:**

```
final Activity activity;
// init the activity
activity.sendMessage(message);
```

**Activity which receives the message:**

```
final void sendMessage(final String message) {
  // do something with your message, here.
}
```